# Blender 3.2 Download instead of 3.3

Tags: versions

I would like to download Blender 3.2 instead of Blender 3.3 because 3.3 is not working properly on my computer. However the Blender website only enables me to download 3.3. (when I click download 3.2 it jumps to the 3.3 file.) How can I get the 3.2 version?

Best regards, Tomas

Comment: you can find all releases for download here https://download.blender.org/release/. to get version 3.2 download it from https://download.blender.org/release/Blender3.2/

Comment: https://dotbow.github.io/Blender-Launcher/

Comment: Hello Harry and hello Markus,

thank you for your help! It worked out perfectly well!

Best regards, Tomas